# Does anyone know why I cant lock my pc

Tags: lock

When I try to lock my PC with the shortcut meta-L or in the power menu nothing happens.
I can lock my PC with `dm-tool lock` but that is not very handy.

Does anyone knows a fix for this problem?

Thanks in advance

Flor

Comment: Can you test re-binding the lock key shortcut in the keyboard settings and see if it works better? You're on Hera 5.1 right?

Comment: I tried it, without any success... But like I said it doesn't even work in the power menu. Yes I am running eOS 5.1.3.

Comment: UP Please, i have the same problem Does any people have a same problem ?